# Combine pandas DataFrame query() method with isin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I want to use `isin()` method with `df.query()`, to select rows with `id` in a list: `id_list`. Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237211/pandas-query-rows-by-list) was asked before, but they used typical `df[df['id'].isin(id_list)]` method. I'm wondering if there is a way to use `df.query()` instead.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('aabbccddeeff'), 'b': list('aaaabbbbcccc'),
                   'c': np.random.randint(5, size=12),
                   'd': np.random.randint(9, size=12)})

id_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And this yields an error

```
df.query('a == id_list')
```

Comment: And what is your motivation for insisting on `query`?  Do you have any sample data?  What have you tried?

Comment: Just feel writing `df` twice or more times is tedious.
According to [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#special-use-of-the-operator-with-list-objects), seems like one cannot put name of the list inside the quotes.

Comment: The package dplyr for R is a good example, where you only need to specify columns names thereafter.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for `query`

> You can refer to variables
>       in the environment by prefixing them with an '@' character like
>       `@a + b`.

In your case:

```
In [38]: df.query('a == @id_list')
Out[38]:
   a  b  c  d
0  a  a  3  4
1  a  a  4  5
2  b  a  2  3
3  b  a  1  5
4  c  b  2  4
5  c  b  1  2
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, this solution seems to be a bit more efficient than using ```a in @id_list```
Executing
```%timeit df.query('a == @id_list')
%timeit df.query('a in @id_list')```

Resulted in:
```1.47 ms ± 244 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.83 ms ± 345 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)```

Answer (score 94):

You can also include the list within the query string:

```
>>> df.query('a in ["a", "b", "c"]')
```

This is the same as:

```
>>> df.query('a in @id_list')
```

Answer (score 7):

This appears to work:

```
>>> df.query('a == {0}'.format(id_list))
   a  b  c  d
0  a  a  4  1
1  a  a  0  7
2  b  a  2  1
3  b  a  0  1
4  c  b  4  0
5  c  b  4  2
```

Whether or not it is more clear is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Interesting, why you came across this idea?

Comment: I don't agree with this approach because is only valid for small `id_list` lengths. What about if your `id_list` has 1 million elements?

Answer (score 3):

You can also call [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) inside [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query('a.isin(@id_list).values')

# or alternatively
df.query('a.isin(["a", "b", "c"]).values')
```

Comment: Thank you. This works without `.values` well too.

Comment: Doesn't work without `values` for me. I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`. pandas 1.3.4.