# filter pandas dataframe on one level of a multi level index

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas dataframe with a multi level index, how can I filter by one of the levels of that index. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,1,2], "time": [1, 1, 2, 2], "val": [1,2,3,4]})
df.set_index(keys=["id", "time"], inplace=True)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
df[df["time"] > 1]
```

but `time` is no longer a column. I could keep it as a column but I don't want to drag around copies of data.

Comment: Are you taking about something along the lines of iterating through a pandas dataframe?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### `query`

```
df.query('time > 1')

         val
id time     
1  2       3
2  2       4
```

---

### `IndexSlice`

DataFrame index must be lexsorted

```
df.sort_index().loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 2:], :]

         val
id time     
1  2       3
2  2       4
```

Comment: really? you have to pass strings around instead of having it in code?

Comment: This is one approach.  Happens to also be a fast one at scale.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/2336654

Comment: @Alex Note; `level = 'time', df.query("@level > 1")` works with variables.

Comment: @piRSquared: alright, i'm sold on the query thing. looks like the the best way to go for me. do people in pandas world generally just build up strings dynamically in code and pass those around? ironically that kind of thing tends to be discouraged in R

Comment: @coldspeed: good tip, was just looking at that in the docs, thanks!

Comment: @coldspeed, I was searching for hooking variables in `.query()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex not necessarily.  You can take coldspeed's tip.  But honestly, if you're looking for more dynamic components, reconsidered MaxU's approach.

Answer (score 27):

```
In [17]: df[df.index.get_level_values('time') > 1]
Out[17]:
         val
id time
1  2       3
2  2       4
```

@piRSquared's solution is more idiomatic though...

Comment: interesting, this is along the lines of what i would have guessed the answer should look like. will keep in mind that query is standard practice

Comment: ^ exactly what I thought. The idiomatic approach gets complicated for a beginner to that method (but who knows the usual way of filtering a df), especially when you'd wanna compare with `.isin()` or something similar. 

I imagined it wouldn't work out of the box since there aren't enough illustrations on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html 

but then I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/33991869/1332401 (so `df[df.A.isin(list_ids)]` vs `df.query('A in @list_ids)`)