# Pandas query does not recognize list defined in the global environment

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I am trying to refer to a list defined in the global environment but this returns an exception.  The operation can be implemented without the use of query but I would like to know how I can do the same with query.

Here is my code:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively:

[image]

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33990955/9987623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), you just need to prefix your variables with an '@' character.  So, in your case, it will be:

```
df = df100.query('ltm_id == @ltm_ids[0]', engine='python')
```